# Referencing self Object in Object.defineProperties

Tags: javascript

I am trying to extend the base Object object to include join function for all objects. The code looks like this (obviously not a valid code):

```
function is_scalar(obj){return (/string|number|boolean/).test(typeof obj);}
Object.defineProperties(Object.prototype, {
    "join": {
        value: (seperator = " ", recursive = false) => {
            var out = [];
            Object.keys(Object).forEach((prop) => {
                if (Array.isArray(Object[prop])) {
                    out.push(Object[prop].join(seperator));
                }
                else if(is_scalar(Object[prop])){
                    out.push(Object[prop]);
                }
            });
            return out.join(seperator);
        },
        enumerable: false
    }
});
```

The problem is I don't know how to reference the instance object for the `Object.Keys` clause.

**Efforts**

I have already tried `this`, but it refers to the `window` object.

I also have tried using `Object` and `Object.prototype` and both look empty.

Comment: You should use an arrow function for something like `is_scalar`, but not for methods! Why not use a simple method shorthand (drop the `:` and the `=>` and it'll work)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Don't use an arrow function.](https://dmitripavlutin.com/when-not-to-use-arrow-functions-in-javascript/)

```js
Object.defineProperties(Object.prototype, {
  "join": {
    value: function (seperator = " ", recursive = false) {
      console.log(this);
    },
    enumerable: false
  }
});


({}).join()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Here's my final working test fiddle, just in case. https://jsfiddle.net/epm3od0x/13/